# Kotlin compileDebugKotlin FAILED,Unresolved reference: RecyclerView

Tags: gradle, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I run the project kotlin-Android as usual,but , it failed.

One module throws error:Unresolved reference: RecyclerView, but I have not change this module for a long time.

I'm confused.

the version is :

> com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1
>
> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
>
> kotlin 1.3.11
>
> compile_sdk_version 28

Thanks so much for any help！

error:

1. Unresolved reference: RecyclerView :

[image]

2. compileDebugKotlin FAILED

[image]

Comment: What is your project structure? Does this happen when building module or main project? Do you have any lint errors (red highlights) while editing or it crashes during build only?

Comment: No lint errors, it crashes during build only. I'v try on an other computer, the code works fine, so i reinstall the system of my computer, it build success now... Thanks a lot for your comment. : )